# Are Ross-Littlewood-sequences or negative probabilities possible in physics?

Tags: probability, mathematics

There are claims that the [Ross-Littlewood paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox) could be simulated in physics.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/315502/ and in particular Paul's answer there.

Also a solution of the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox using extended probabilities as invented by Dirac, Bartlett, and Wigner has been considered.

W. Mückenheim: "A resolution of the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox", Lett. Nuovo Cim. 35 (1982) 300-304. [W. Mückenheim et al.: "A review of extended probabilities", Phys. Rep. 133 (1986) pp. 337-401.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157386901109)

But are they really physical? An opinion refusing this is:

> 'If nontrivial set theory, non-constructive mathematics or a non-measurable set is used in an essential way, it cannot be physically relevant'.

Jakob Kellner: "Pitowsky's Kolmogorovian models and super-determinism", [arXiv:1606.06849](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06849).

My question: Are there genuine physical examples supporting or contradicting this opinion?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20370/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46684/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43853/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27303/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Duplicate questions removed.