# Can the universe be round but still infinite?

Tags: cosmology, differential-geometry, curvature, geometry, topology

1. Can the universe still be infinite in space if its curvature is > 1?
2. Is a manifold of positive curvature necessarily compact?
3. Does the [Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) have any bearing on the finite or infinite character of a compact manifold?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? Replace the word _universe_ with the word _manifold,_ and it is a pure mathematical question.

Comment: But here part of the question is: are these the right mathematics to answer this question or is there a more appropriate framework to discuss a possible answer.

Comment: In particular, I believe Tarski's may have no bearing.

Comment: Subquestion 2 (v2) has trivial counterexamples. Subquestion 3 (v2) is a possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20370/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Would you care to give some details ?- I'd certainly upvote such an answer - In your counterexamples, do you mean curvature bounded from below by a positive $\epsilon>0$ or can the curvature be locally nought in your examples: I have read that Bonnet-Myers theorem has some kind of analogue in a Lorentzian manifold but would like to understand this further. Also, I think this question, although mathematical, has direct physical interest, especially for the cosmologically naive like me.